# Running XCTest on iphone device

Tags: xctest

I am trying to run XCTest on iphone device but Xcode show be following message.

```
"Logic Testing on iOS devices is not supported. You can run logic tests on the Simulator."
```

Is there any way by which I can run the XCTest on device?

Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found that using GHUnit we can run unit tests on iphone device. Internally it uses xctest. Here is how you setup [GHUnit](http://iosunittesting.com/installing-ghunit-on-xcode-4-6/).

I was able to follow the instructions and setup unit tests using xcode 5.